# use of undeclared identifier in 'c'

Tags: c, do-while, cs50

```
int get_cents(void)
{
    do
    {
        int i = get_int("How many cents customer is owed?: ");
    }   while (i < 0);
    return i;
}
```

I am beginner and i am stuck at this problem and getting error >use of undeclared identifier

Comment: `i` isn't visible outside the loop. Declare it outside.

Comment: And then make sure you do not redeclare `i` inside the loop because it would hide the `i` declared outside the loop. I.e. change the declaration and initialization of `i` inside the loop to a simple assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the scope of variables in c. Keeping it simple, a variable is visible inside the `{}` where it has been declared, so in your case the variable `i` does not exists outside the loop. A correct solution for your code is:

```
int get_cents(void)
{
   int i;
   do
   {
      i = get_int("How many cents customer is owed?: ");
   } while (i < 0);
   return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, variables have a scope. Means the variables have a limit of till where can it be used... The scope of any variable is only till the closing brace of the compound body it was written in. For eg:

```
if(true){
    int x = 999;
}
x++;
```

This operation cannot be performed since x is declared inside the compound body of `if()` block so it's using limit is only till the `if()` block... Even if you do not put braces, the block remains the same so still you will get an error... This is what I mean...

```
if(true)
    int x = 999;
x++;
```

Even though there is no braces `{}` used but still this code will give you output since again, `x` is declared within the `if()` block and is used outside it...

So in your program, just you are declaring variable `i` inside the `do...while()` loop so it cannot be used at the condition of the `do...while()` loop since that is considered as out of the `do...while()` block. So this is what should you write then...

```
int get_cents(void)
{
   int i;
   do
   {
      i = get_int("How many cents customer is owed?: ");
   } while (i < 0);
   return i;
}
```